# How to stream a audio of incoming call via bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am able to receive, hangup and dial a number from my `headset` to `android mobile` which are connected via `bluetooth`.

Now, once I receive a in-coming call of mobile in headset, I need to speak with the called person from headset. I need to **stream my voice via bluetooth to android mobile**.  I am searching for this code.

Crawled n number of post but could not get appropriate answer, Currently  am using below but its not working...

```
AudioManager audioManager;

audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

I am not sure after this what line of code I need to write to achieve my requirement

Note: I receive in-coming call by sending `mmOutStream.write("ATA\r".getBytes());` this AT command to my Android mobile.

Please correct and guide me to perform audio stream.

Answer (score 2):

You should set speakerphone to false, otherwise your output will be re-directed there. It is enough to do this:

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

Also, you can  optionally set microphone to un-mute state (just in case previous state was muted):

```
mAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
```